# Textfield appears as an action in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

Why my `Textfield` appears as an `IBAction`?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

check that you set class name in identity inspector tab for viewController

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Kiruthiga check class name of `UITextField`, and also check u should select `IBOutlet` instead of Action when u connect connection by dragging.This will help u

Comment: Check out the screenshot, Xcode was not showing any option for selecting option as outlet. It have been blocked. If I was trying to refer it to view controller.swift it automatically shows as insert action kind of.

Comment: U can als use @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!
and then connect IBOutlet from storyboard

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to define the custom class for the view controller you are wanting to connect outlets from inside the Identity Inspector (this same problem happened to me).

1. Select the view controller with the text fields you want to connect to code.
2. Go to Identity Inspector in the utilities panel and the first field should say "class" [(Identity Inspector Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjXhe.png)
3. Fill this box with either the name of the file of the code you want to connect to the selected view controller, or you must create a new view controller file. To do this, you can go to File > New > Cocoa Touch Class. Then for "Subclass of" box put UIViewController, name it, then press enter.
4. The file you just created should come up as a .swift file (make sure this file is within the hierarchy of the app files as it tends to be created outside of it!)
5. Go into the "Class" box from the Identity Inspector and insert the name of the file you just created (it should come up automatically when you being typing).

Control-Dragging the text field to this file should now give you the option to treat it as an outlet rather than forcing it to be an action!

Answer (score 1):

It's due to that `LaunchScreen.storyboard` - try in `main.storyboard`

Answer (score 0):

You can change it according to your requirement :

[image]

Comment: If I was dragging and dropping a text field, assistant editor with large codings shows up ? how to then refer and where to refer this text field ?

Answer (score 0):

Select collection type as outlet. Here you selected action which means action s that to be performed on clicking textfiled

Comment: How to create reference for textfield from main.storyboard to view controller.swift ? Tell me how to create a new swift file for a view controller located inside main.storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible ways to get back.

1) Select `UITextField` if any class name already selected remove/clear it.

2) Maybe It looks like a problem on Xcode builds because of `Object` as `Exit`. So please clean and rebuild the project. try close project reopens it.

3) Check u should select `IBOutlet`/`Outlet` instead of `Action` when you connecting connection by dragging.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` Can have `IBAction` of `Editing Changed` event. so you don't need to surprise on that part.
If you want to create `IBOutlet` drag to empty area not to `IBAction` function.

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Check your class...you have to assign a class to that ViewController....after assigning the class the problem will get resolved @kiruthiga